# How can I keep the input data structure in a for loop?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples which looks like this:

```
l = [('xx-1711640.html', 'Hello'), 
     ('xx-8411747.html', 'Bye')
    ]
```

The actual list got thousand of entries. Now I want to use an regex for the tuples. To do this I have a for loop. Additionally I want the output to be also a list of tuples.

My code:

```
ret = []
for line in l:
    for i in line:
        try:
            reg = re.sub(r'.+-', '', i)
            ret.append(reg)
        except:
            print(line)
```

However with this code my output looks like this:

```
ret = ['1711640.html', 'Hello', '8411747.html', 'Bye']
```

When I want it to look like this:

```
ret = [('1711640.html', 'Hello'), ('8411747.html', 'Bye')]
```

How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
ret = []
for m,n in l:  #unpack tuple
    try:
        m = re.sub(r'.+-', '', m)   
        ret.append((m, n))
    except:
        print(m,n)
```

**Output:**

```
[('1711640.html', 'Hello'), ('8411747.html', 'Bye')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a one-liner without the exception handling:

```
>>> [(re.sub(r'.+-', '', x), re.sub(r'.+-', '', y)) for x, y in l]
[('1711640.html', 'Hello'), ('8411747.html', 'Bye')]
```

Comment: I used a list comprhension previously, but I cant include try and except with this method.

Comment: Fair enough, just thought I'd include it for completeness!